# How to change value (from selecting) but not change the reference value

Tags: angular, typescript

I got a problem in angular framework
when I click to choose value form ng-for

```
<tr *ngFor="let dept of department" (click)="clinicChoose(dept)">
  <td class="text-center">{{dept.sectionCode}}</td>
  <td>{{dept.sectionName}}</td>
  <td class="text-center" [style.color]="dept.flagStatus == 0 ? 'blue' : 'red'"></td>
</tr>
```

in clinicChoose function is

```
 clinicChoose(dept: CSection) {
    this.clinic = dept
  }
```

and then at the UI when I change value in `this.clinic` like `this.clinic.flagStatus == 1`
value that I choose in table is change too!!
I don't want it change, so what should I do?

when click row (red) on table I will get data (green)
[image]

but when I change something, data in table that I choose is changed too whyyyyyyy

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform a deep cloning of your `dept` when assigning it. So, create a function (or use a library) that clones an object and assign it like `this.clinic = deepClone(dept)`; Your `this.clinic` will be a separate object now and will not affect the original list anymore.

Comment: thank you so much I try this    this.currentData.dept = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dept));   and it's work

Comment: Just note that JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dept)); will work, however, it's unpredictable and may not work correctly with Dates and probably other types, converting them to string. I'd suggest to use another approach, or you can leave as is if you are okay with it.